# How does gear improvement work?

Tags: splatoon-2

So in splatoon 2 there are different kind of 'armors', those being classified by stars (1 star, 2 stars, 3 stars). Each of these stars grants to the item one more random perk (or this is what I guess from what I've seen).

I managed to give one additional perk to a '2 stars' item so it got all the perks but still being a '2 stars' item. Is it as good as a 3 stars item now? Is there a difference anymore?

If I clean the perks of this 2 stars item will it lose the additional slot?

Any additional information about armor improvement and management will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All that the stars mean is how many slots it comes with. A two star item with an extra slot unlocked is identical to a three star item.

Cleaning the abilities on gear does not remove any additional slots you gave it.

Comment: Glad to read that. So I can take any fashion clothing and transform it into a powerful piece of armor. I forgot to ask something else: Can the main perk of an armor be changed?

Comment: @Grirg No, the main ability of gear cannot be changed. At a high level you can use this to your advantage -- if you see your opponent is wearing a Shrimp Pink Polo, for example, then you know they've got Ninja Squid.

Comment: @Pyritie True though that may be, in Splatoon 2 you can also just look at the map screen and see the three primary abilities of each opponent (and your teammates).